# How to write a function that processes input from an Edit box in Win32?

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I'm a noob here, but I've learned the basics of C++ and am learning Win32 as I go.

I made a basic Win32 window with a text box in the primary window, and I want to have the program respond in some way to the text a user types in when they press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, even if its just a small dialog box.

However, I'm not sure how to begin the function that would do this. I feel like using a `switch` statement with `VK_RETURN` in my `WndProc` is how it would execute, but I don't know how to include the "EDIT" box into the function.

Hopefully I stated this question in a way that makes sense.

Comment: If you're new to the Windows API, you should follow the official guide, it's quite good https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows

Comment: Having a single-line edit control in a dialog handle the \[Enter\] key is fairly advanced. You will have to modify the control's behavior by handling the [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031126-00/?p=41703) message. This necessitates [subclassing the control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview). That's an advanced topic.

Answer (score 0):

`GetWindowText` to get the text from the control, `GetDlgItem` to find it. `GetDlgItemInt` or `GetDlgItemText`to do both at once.

Answer (score 0):

In a dialog box, when user perssed ENTER key, it generally caused the default or focused control to respond the event, while it is not expected as you desires.

You can set the edit control in "multiple line" mode, and make "Want Return" property checked. then in the DlgProc of the dialog, whenever the edit's content is changed, you receive WM_COMMAND message, with LOWORD(wParam) is the edit's ID, HIWORD(wParam) is EN_CHANGE. then you can get the edit's content to check if user has pressed ENTER key to make the change.